# Half Wave Voltage Doubler Simulation stuck

Tags: ltspice, simulation, multiplier, charge-pump, voltage-doubler

I'm trying to simulate the following circuit on LTSpice

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6t7tL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitors have `10Meg` Parallel Resistance

```
.model D_ideal D(Ron=0.1n Roff=10Meg Vfwd=0.7)
```

And I'm using a voltage switch and a diode for my SCR model:

```
.SUBCKT SCR 1 2 4
S1 3 1 2 0 VSW
D1 3 4 D_ideal 
.MODEL VSW SW(RON=0.1n  ROFF = 10Meg VT = 1 VH = 0)
.model D_ideal D(Ron=0.1n Roff=10Meg Vfwd=0.7)
.ENDS
```

When **CHRG** turns off the SCR my simulation gets stuck.

Any insights?

Comment: Try throwing a 10Meg resistor across D1, and/or right-click D1 and change it's model to one with more parameters.

Comment: Already tried it, also Roff=10Meg

Comment: It could be the "simplicity" of the diode model. Ideal diodes can be difficult to model without such parameters as reverse leakage current, transition time, etc. The matrix compiler chokes on trying to model events which happen too quickly - due to the missing values. So it sits, trying to model ever faster and shorter events, until it goes beyond the GMIN step value (time) and it either freezes, or halts. Could try going into the options and enabling the alternate solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely culprit I see is the switch who doesn't use negative histeresys, as recommended by the manual. Positive and/or no histeresys makes it switch abruptly between the on/off resistances, while a negative histeresys will allow a smooth transition, thus allowing the solver pass the hops with elegance and dignity.

For the ideal diode you could try adding `epsilon=100m revepsilon=50m`, they set the quadratic region of the I-V curve's "knee". Also, the dynamic resistances you chose for the diode are quite far one from another (in orders of magnitude), which could pose problems. I think it's more than safe to choose `Ron=1m Roff=1Meg`.